# EXCEL VBA DATETIME subtraction

Tags: vba, datetime, excel

This question was asked before and i tried to implement that solution but I can't get it to work
THis is basically what I am trying to achive
To subtract datetime values to get the number of total hours EVEN if it is beyond a day then the value I would like to display is 36:03, this is in the format [h]:mm, tks, below is the VBA code I am trying to implement

```
 Sub dateissue()
Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
Dim doublevar As Double

enddate = "13/2/2014 08:10:00"
startdate = "12/2/2014 18:10:00"

doublevar = enddate - startdate
Range("D3").Value = Format(doublevar, "[h]:mm")


End Sub
```

My result in D3 is always **:12**
any reason why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
Range("D3").Value = doublevar
Range("D3").NumberFormat = "[h]:mm"
```

Also make sure that you input dates in correct format (i.e. month/day order, system regional settings may affect this on different machines).

Or if you want ONLY text:

```
Range("D3").Value = "'" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(doublevar, "[h]:mm")
```

Comment: this works great!, just another thing lets say I have to store the hours and then add these hours. As the whole program is in a loop.

Comment: Same thing, just store these hours in Double type var and add them (they are actually stored in Excel number format: value 1 means 24 hours, 2 - 48 hours etc).